# Geolocation APIs: SimpleGeo vs CityGrid vs PublicEarth vs Twitter vs Foursquare vs Loopt vs Fwix. How to retrieve venue/location information?

Tags: facebook, api, geolocation, twitter

We need to display meta information (e.g, address, name) on our site for various venues like bars, restaurants, and theaters.

Ideally, users would type in the name of a venue, along with zip code, and we present the closest matches.

Which APIs have people used for similar geolocation purposes? What are the pros and cons of each?

Our basic research yielded a few options (listed in title and below). We're curious to hear how others have deployed these APIs and which ones are ultimately in use.

- Fwix API: http://developers.fwix.com/
- Zumigo

Does Facebook plan on offering a Places API eventually that could accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note: we don't need a mobile component.

Comment: The Google Places API could be interesting to you (as an additional consideration to the others you mentioned): http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Comment: thanks, @dermatthias. why don't you post as an answer then i can award you points if no one else responds.

Comment: Done. But you can also upvote comments (left side of comment), and because my answer wasn't a real (complete) answer, I just wrote a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook Places is based on Factual.  You can use Factual's API which is pretty good (and still free, I think?)

http://www.factual.com/topic/local

You can also use unauthenticated Foursquare as a straight places database.  The data is of uneven quality since it's crowdsourced, but I find it generally good.  It's free to a certain API limit, but I think the paid tier is negotiated.

https://developer.foursquare.com/

I briefly looked at Google Places but didn't like it because of all the restrictions on how you have to display results (Google wants their ad revenue).

Answer (score 5):

It's been a long time since this question was asked but a quick update on answers for other people.

This post, right now at least, will not go into great detail about each service but merely lists them:

- http://wiki.developer.factual.com/w/page/12298852/start
- http://developer.yp.com
- http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation
- https://developer.foursquare.com/
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
- https://simplegeo.com/docs/api-endpoints/simplegeo-context
- http://www.citygridmedia.com/developer/
- http://fwix.com/developer_tools
- http://localeze.com/

They each have their pros and cons (i.e. Google Places only allows 20 results per query, Foursquare and Facebook Places have semi-unreliable results) which can be explained a bit more in detail, although not entirely, in the following link. http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-each-Places-API

For my own project I ended up deciding to go with Factual's API since there are no restrictions on what you do with the data (one of the only ToS' that I've read in its entirety). Factual has a pretty reliable API, which as a user of the API you may update, modify, or flag rows of the data. Facebook Places bases their data on Factual's, just another fact to shed some perspective.

Hope I can be of help to any future searchers.

Comment: Does Factual allow you to download their data to store on your own database to limit lag time for each ping?

Comment: I read somewhere from their website that you're not supposed to copy the data for your own internal uses (but I'm a bit befuddled on that one since their ToS doesn't seem to explicitly deny this) but they offer developers the opportunity to download datasets. However, you do have to apply to them in order to get a dataset to download.

Comment: Just checked http://www.factual.com/tos and section 4 states:

Raw data, facts, and general ideas are not protected by copyright law. You acknowledge that Factual may host, serve, reproduce, distribute, and allow the modification of data uploaded and made publicly available in connection with the Site or Services, and that other Factual users may reproduce, distribute, modify, manipulate, or build upon such data. Likewise, you may reproduce, distribute, modify, and manipulate or build upon data publicly available on Factual, subject to all conditions and disclaimers in these Terms of Use.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, because I havn't compared the given geolocation API, but there is also the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/places/), which solves a similiar problem like the other APIs.

One thing about SimpleGeo: The Location API of SimpleGeo supports mainly US (and Canada?) based locations. The last time I checked, my home country Germany doesn't has many known locations.

Comment: SimpleGeo was acquired by Urban Airship and [will be shut down](http://urbanairship.com/blog/2012/01/12/update-on-our-plan-to-integrate-location-and-context-services-into-our-push-messaging-platform), so that's even less of an option anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison between places data APIs is tough to keep up to date, with the fast past of the space, and with acquisitions like SimpleGeo and HyperPublic changing the landscape quickly.

So I'll just throw in CityGrids perspective as of February 2012.  CityGrid provides 18M US places, allowing up to 10M requests per month for developers (publishers) at no charge.

You can search using a wide range of "what" and "where" (Cities, Neighborhoods, Zip Codes, Metro Areas, Addresses, Intersections) searches including latlong.  We have rich data for each place including images, videos, reviews, offers, etc.

CityGrid also has a developer revenue sharing program where we'll pay you to display some places as well as large mobile and web advertising network.

You can also query Places via the CityGrid API using Factual, Foursquare and other places providers places and venue IDs.  We aggregate data from several places data providers through our system.

Website: http://developer.citygridmedia.com/